# Windows 11 22h2, storecli64.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, raid

[image]

Annoyingly, the `storcli64.exe` starts up, but doesn't recognise any of the commands.

I need to configure my RAID controller and update the firmware, but the download command isn't working either.

The file is in `system32`, and I haven't changed the path.

It does indeed start up, and I have verified it with `signtool.exe`

Comment: Have you tried storecli64.exe (with the file extension)?

Comment: you mean put storcli64.exe and then the command? ill try that and report back

Comment: oh this worked! problem is that this happens now:

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>storcli64.exe /c0 download file=9460-8i_nopad.rom
CLI Version = 007.2408.0000.0000 Nov 15, 2022
Operating system = Windows 11
Controller = 0
Status = Failure
Description = Failed to validate Image file 9460-8i_nopad.rom

Comment: That's already a different thing. Where is the _9460-8i_nopad.rom_ file located? If it's not in the System32 folder how do you want it to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running ***storcli64.exe*** works, you might need to use the full executable file name (not just *storcli64* without the *exe*) in your command.

So what you should enter is:

```
storcli64.exe /c0 download file=9460-8i_nopad.rom
```

---

On a separate note, you are (the CLI shell) in `C:\Windows\System32` and that's not where the **9460-8i_nopad.rom** file is. You need to open the command prompt in the directory where the file is extracted (or `cd` to that directory.)